# macOS 10.13: Windows 10 installation with Boot Camp

Tags: bootcamp, windows, partition, error, high-sierra

I tried to install Windows 10 via Boot Camp, but got stuck at the creating a new partition part. The error states:

> An error occurred while partitioning the disk. Please run disk utility
>   to check and fix the error.

Here's what I did:

- Run first aid on my internal drive
- Decrypted the internal drive
- Start in Cmd + S mode and run the /sbin/fsck -fy command
- Reinstall Mac OS High Sierra

After all this, I still get the same partitioning error as before.

**How can I install Windows 10 properly with Boot Camp?**

Comment: I ran into the same error repeatedly. Every time I had to re-pave things in Disk Utility from Recovery mode. Then, I would boot into Internet Recovery and reinstall. Every time I tried again, same error, same horrible state of partitions.

Comment: Have you tried partitioning manually with disk utility?

Answer (score 2):

> This question is possibly related to 
>   [Disk Could Not Be Partitioned - First Aid not helping](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/302211/1097) — I'm duplicating my
>   answer here.

I had very similar problem. After contacting Apple Support and following their instructions, I've reinstalled macos ([instructions here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904)). This is not a wipeout reinstall, but do make a backup.

After the reinstall partitioning worked like a charm.

And so do Bootcamp installation.

Answer (score 1):

There is likely an error that Apple's disk utility can't cope with. There are few options.

1. Third party disk repair utility, but are there any that are compatible with High Sierra and APFS. Not sure/don't think so.
2. Verify you have a good backup, boot into recovery mode and repartition the drive, which should fix the errors assuming they are soft errors and not hardware errors.

Number 2 has the benefit (?!) of allowing you to set a partition size for your Mac volume and leaving the rest unformatted and ready for Win 10.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Time Machine for your backups then this may fix it.

1. In **System Preferences**, untick *“Back Up Automatically”* in the **Time
   Machine** preference.
2. Run the tmutil command in the **Terminal** app;

   ```
   tmutil thinlocalsnapshots / 9999999999999999
   ```

   basically, it will remove all the local backups on your boot drive, it won’t delete any of your files on your Time Machine backup drive.
3. Once the command finishes, start the **Boot Camp Assistant** app and
   try again, it should work now.
4. When you have Windows installed remember to re-enable **Time
   Machine** on the Mac side.

[Source / more info](https://blog.adriel.co.nz/2019/01/06/installing-windows-on-a-mac-getting-your-disk-could-not-be-partitioned-error/)