# Disk Could Not Be Partitioned - First Aid not helping

Tags: macos, bootcamp, partition, high-sierra, apfs

I am trying to install Windows by Bootcamp on my MacBook Air (2017) 128 GB. I am using the newest macOS, so High Sierra. Unfortunately I am getting "Disk Could Not Be Partitioned" error. I tried to use First Aid and "/sbin/fsck -fy" from Single User Mode and there aren't any errors.

What can I do to fix my problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had very similar problem. After contacting Apple Support and following their instructions, I've reinstalled macos ([instructions here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904)). This is not a wipeout reinstall, but do make a backup.

After the reinstall partitioning worked like a charm.